# Firebase Cloud Messaging Not Sending to iOS (stuck on "scheduled")

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notifications to users through Firebase Cloud Messaging (testing sending from the console) and Flutter.

I have:

- given Push Notification and Background Mode (fetch & remote) capability in Xcode
- created an APN key, linked with Google Firebase with respective identifier (that has permission to send Push Notifications) and bundle ID.
- Created this function in "main":

```
void internNotifications() async {
    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    String token = await messaging.getToken(
      vapidKey:
          "BP_yTdkgwyo2GEdNdjn8KIz874lEdaKaDWVz5wHKpb1_48RBU4UKUmPiRhG1DT7ViHvY7cy8goNZOQE3a0X6yiM",
    );

    RemoteMessage initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    if (initialMessage != null) {
      _handleMessage(initialMessage);
    }

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);

    NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
  }

  void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.data['type'] == 'chat') {
      Navigator.pushNamed(
        context,
        '/chat',
      );
    }
  }
```

When I attempt to send a firebase cloud notification to my users of a particular bundle while simulating via Xcode on my physical device, Firebase reads that the notification is "scheduled" and nothing goes through.

To ensure, I have tried this when the app is in the foreground and background (but not completed exited)

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is on Firebase's end and not iOS. You should check the schedule of the notification: [Firebase Scheduling Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4csAZ.png)